# Path corrupted after installing rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

It's pretty weird, but i got my PATH corrupted after installing rvm on Mac OS. I really don't understand why but i get command not found in every command i type, from 'port' to 'git'. That behaviour is really really weird, do you have any idea why this happens ? ( i installed using this : http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Comment: Obvious questions: What does `echo $PATH` show? Where is `git` installed? How did you install rvm?

Comment: I can fix the path manually, but that is not the point. It worked fine right before i installed. I installed from the url i specify in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your .bash_profile was overwritten or somehow changed. I assume you have git installed as a macport. My guess is that the path to all macport installed executables was removed from your $PATH variable.

Make sure that you have the following line in your .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: yes ! I must have used 'touch .bash_profile' and truncated the previous path, in order to write the command from rvm. Thanx, this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unfortunately the rvm installer DOES overwrite the contents of .bashrc and .bash_profile.
Happened to me too, but luckily I had a back up .bash_profile with all of my aliases, functions, and path defns.
Something needs to be fixed here.